# Set custom added PATH vars to work in each Terminal session

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I ran these 2 commands simply in the terminal:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/milkncookiez/Developer/android-studio/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/home/milkncookiez/Developer/PhpStorm/bin"
```

in the 2 bin folders I have the files `studio.sh` and `phpstorm.sh`. In that same terminal session when I simply wrote the name of the files - the programs were ran.

When I opened another terminal - did not work. I added these both lines in the `~/.profile` file, opened a new terminal session but it still does not work. How do I set the 2 variable changes to be permanent for all terminal sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding them to `~/.profile` (apply to your user) or a `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` file (apply to the entire system) is the correct way. In order for the change to apply, you have to log out of your system and log back in, as `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` are loaded when you login.

To 'reload' ~/.profile in a running terminal, you can use `source ~/.profile`

Comment: `/etc/profile` should preferably not be edited directly. Better to add a new `/etc/profile.d/<somename>.sh` file. Anyway, given the paths added to `PATH` in this case, `~/.profile` is probably the suitable choice.

Comment: @Gunnar I'm not familiar with the /etc/profile.d directory so I can't confirm whether that's the case or not, but please edit my answer if using /etc/profile.d is best practice.

Comment: Ok, done. The source is the tutorial [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables), and I edited that section in consultation with experienced Ubuntu developers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `export`; the `PATH` variable is already exported at that point. Anyway, `.profile` is read when you log in, so what you've done is correct, but opening a new terminal does not count as logging in.

Comment: I habitually use `export` when dealing with environment variables in `~/.profile`. It's true that it's not necessary when modifying an already existing environment variable such as `PATH`, but I'm probably not going to do it otherwise in the future. That way I eliminate the risk for forgetting `export` when it's needed. ;)